# Java stream filter behavior

Tags: java, collections, filter, count

I have a `Dailyline` class with this method :

```
public boolean isAtMostThreeDaysBefore(Dailyline dailyline) {
    DateTime toCompare = new DateTime(this.year, this.month, this.day, 0, 0);
    DateTime baseDay = new DateTime(dailyline.year, dailyline.month, dailyline.day, 0, 0);
    int daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(toCompare.toLocalDate(), baseDay.toLocalDate()).getDays();

    return (daysBetween >= 1 && daysBetween <= 3);
}
```

which compare 2 `dailyline` and return if the one passed is the one of the preceding 3 days. This function works well.

I also have a `List<Dailyline> dailylines` and This problematic function :

```
for (Dailyline dailyline : dailylines) {
    System.out.println(dailylines.size());
    Long lastThreeDays = dailylines.stream().filter(d -> d.isAtMostThreeDaysBefore(dailyline)).count();
    System.out.println(lastThreeDays);
}
```

Edit-- There shouldn't be any `lastThreeDays` higher than 3, both because dailyline are unique by date (year-month-day) and because I tested the numebr of true returned by the boolean method.

My `dailylines` list is untouched, like I want, and stay with 32698 items, but the 'lastThreeDays' I do not know why...I tested with only 1 dailyline without the loop and there was 2 `true` return in the `isAtMostThreeDaysBefore`...

```
32698
0
32698
347
32698
324
32698
322
32698
338
32698
329
...
...
```

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. My guess is that the data isn't what you think it is, but it's hard to know for sure...

Comment: You say there are no two `Dailyline`s with the same day... that means, you have nearly 100 years of data? Maybe there can not be two dailylines with the same date for the same product, or user, but you have the dailylines for multiple products or users or whatever in the same list?

Comment: @tobias_k I feel stupid at the moment, your comment made me realise that I forgot another parameter outside the Date that need to be also equals...damn thanks